# Hex String Value to Long variable in java

Tags: java, string, hex, memory-address

I'm trying to store the hex value which is in String format into a Long variable. But none of the Long class methods are working as shown in the below code template.

Can anyone help me how to write hex values from string to long?

```
class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        long l1Address = 0x2158F379L;
        long l2Address = 0x1137B372L;
        long l3Address = 0x7198F371L;
        
        String hexAddress = "0x333FF639L";
        // Expectation is long l4Address = 0x333FF639L;
        long l4Address = Long.parseLong(hexAddress,16);
        System.out.println(l4Address);
       /* Gives Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
          For input string: "0x333FF639" */

        hexAddress = "333FF639L";
        // Expectation is long l4Address = 0x333FF639L;
        long l4Address = Long.decode(hexAddress,16);
        System.out.println(l4Address);
        /* Gives 859829817 instead of 333FF639L */
        
        
    }
}
```

I want to store as **long l4Address = 0x333FF639L** which is from String;
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The code you posted has compile errors that you need to fix...

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code?

Comment: I suggest removing any code that doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I have just added the reference code to make developers understand the question.
Could you please post anyway to store hex values(0x333FF639) to long variable.

Answer (score 2):

several things

1. remove the "public final" in front of your variables.
2. use Long.decode(str)
3. remove the trailing 'L' from your hex address

Comment: Regarding point 2, either `Long.decode("0x333FF639")` or `Long.parseLong("333FF639", 16)` (the latter does not include the `0x`) will work.

Comment: When used decode or parseLong the string value is converted to an equivalent decimal number i.e 859829817 instead of 0x333FF639.

Comment: @Coder That's not a problem. A number is just a concept. If your issue is that you want it to be _represented_ in hexadecimal (i.e., base 16) when you go to print/display it, then use something like [`Long#toHexString(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)) or [`Long#toString(long,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#toString(long,int)). Otherwise, by default, the `long` will be _represented_ in base 10 (i.e., decimal), as that is the most commonly used base by humans.